# what does operator"" overloading mean in C++?

Tags: c++

In codeproject, i found a interesting program which implements a meaning of unit ,like

```
unsigned long long operator"" s(unsigned long long n)
{
    return n + 1;
}
int main()
{
    int x = 16s;
}
```

x will be 17, so interesting. can someone tell me what magic this is?

Comment: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/user_literal

Comment: This is one of those "you can only find out if you already know" problems. Given how effective googling for `operator""` is, I don't think it was the best choice of syntax.

Comment: For this sort of problems it's better to rely on search engines other than google https://stackoverflow.com/q/4685615/817643

Comment: @molbdnilo Should google-ability be a criteria of syntax design?

Comment: If you concern about *privacy*, you shouldn't use google at all!